# NSButton doesn't rotate correctly with Xcode 12.2

Tags: macos, animation, cocoa, calayer, nsbutton

I have a `square` `NSButton` set using auto layout in a storyboard.
The button is set as `Image only` and I use the `NSRefreshTemplate` system image.

This is my code to made it spin

```
static BOOL _animate = NO;
- (void)animateRefreshButton:(BOOL)animate
{
    NSButton *btn = _refreshButton;
    [btn setWantsLayer:YES];
    
    // Set the anchor point of the refresh button
    CALayer *btnLayer = btn.layer;
    NSRect frame = btn.frame;
    btnLayer.position = NSMakePoint(NSMidX(frame), NSMidY(frame)); // position to centre of frame
    btnLayer.anchorPoint = NSMakePoint(0.5, 0.5); // anchor point to centre - specified in unit coordinates
    
    _animate = animate;
    
    if (animate)
    {
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        animation.delegate = self;
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2 * M_PI];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
        animation.duration = 0.6; // Speed
        animation.repeatCount = 1;// INFINITY; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.
        animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        
        [btn.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"refreshbutton.rotation"];
    }
}
```

This has been working fine until I build with the new `Xcode 12.2` beta on `MacOS 11.0`. Now the buttons spin doesn't seem to be central.

If I set the button `Scaling` to `None` it will spin centrally fine but the image is far too small. If I set the `Scaling` to `Proportionately Up or Down` so the image fills the button, it spins weird.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Why do you set your anchor point to `0.5`, wouldn't `0.0` be the center?

Comment: 0.5 is the center https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint

Comment: I see that now, thanks; what happens if you try and set the frame to a fixed size? (eg. `NSRect frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20`)?

Comment: I’ll see. I’m starting to think this is a new bug.

Comment: Such is the case with betas, or they've changed something and it's not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

On Catalina it still works even with Xcode 12 beta. Problem seems to be, that with macOS 11 Big Sur the button is no longer centrally aligned.

That can be tested like this:

```
button.image = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameRefreshTemplate];
[button.cell setBackgroundColor:NSColor.redColor];
```

[image: big sur vs catalina]

This is different on Catalina, where the button is centrally aligned. Maybe this is a bug in Big Sur that will be fixed in an upcoming version. For both variants I used Xcode 12.2 beta 2. So it related to the OS and not Xcode beta.

**Workaround**

Draw a refresh icon in a centrally aligned way and use your custom icon, e.g.

```
button.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"my_refresh_icon"];
```

Then the animation works as well on Catalina as on macOS Big Sur.

**Test**

[image: animation]

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Are you saying to draw the image the correct size as needed so the button doesn't need to align it, or is it just that the system image is not centred?

Comment: In Big Sur, this `NSImageNameRefreshTemplate` system icon in the button is at least not centered correctly (for whatever reason), see the distance to the bottom button border, as you can see in the first screenshot of Big Sur. So if the button rotates around the center (red rectangular area), this gives the effect you show in your question.

Comment: The circular part of the icon I drew is completely centered. Visually this is not obvious at first sight because of the arrowhead, but I used guidelines for the construction. The symbol itself could of course be created a bit more carefully, was only for testing purposes, for productive use I would rather use PDF than PNG. Here is a link to the symbol, if that is helpful: https://www.software7.biz/iertzzlmckljkjlmrls/my_refresh_icon.png

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to figure this out. It does seem that the issue is with the `NSImageNameRefreshTemplate` image as using my own image works fine.